# Show that a collection S with projections on U (open in $\mathbb{R}$ is a sub-basis for a topology on $\mathbb{R^{n}}$

Tags: general-topology

[image]

This is the problem and below is the solution for this. Can someone verify this and let me know if its correct or wrong. Give better notation and style if you want to.

[image: tion]

Comment: Given a set $X$ of the poer set of any other set $Y,$ then there exists a minimal topology on $Y$ containing $X.$ By _definition_ $X$ is called a subbasis of this topology (called induced by $X$ on $Y$).

Comment: yeah true......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that all sets $\pi_i^{-1}[U]$ are open in the product topology, because $\pi_i$ is continuous as a map from $\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$, where the domain has the product topology. And the generated base from $\mathcal{S}$ contains all sets of the form

$$U_1 \times U_2 \times \ldots \times U_n = \bigcap_{i=1}^n \pi_i^{-1}[U_i]$$

and so the generated base from $\mathcal{S}$ is precisely the base for the product topology on $\Bbb R^n$. So $\mathcal{S}$ then is *by definition* a subbase for the product topology on $\Bbb R^n$.

If you want to show that $\mathcal{S}$ is a subbase for *some* topology, then if your text follows Munkres (!) you only need to check that $$\bigcup \mathcal{S} = \Bbb R^n$$

and this is trivial : $U=\Bbb R$ is open in $\Bbb R$ and $\pi_i^{-1}[\Bbb R]= \Bbb R^n$ for any $i \le n$, so $\Bbb R^n$ is even a *member* of $\mathcal{S}$ making the union condition immediate.

Comment: thanks a lot, I got this.

Answer (score 0):

Any set of subsets is a sub-basis for the topology they generate.  Perhaps you wish to show it's a sub_basis for the product topology.

Comment: well the question says I need to show its a subbasis and not basis for a topology on $\mathbb{R^{n}}$, thats why I showed dat its only a sub-basis.

Comment: hmm.  because any sibset pf the power sset is a subbasis for _a_ topology, namely, the one it generates.  Did it specify the usual topology on $\Bbb R^n$.  Likely.

Comment: okay great, so my proof looks good right?

Comment: Change the "a" before topology to 'the'.    You have the right idea, i think.   But, one could certainly ask for a few more details.

Comment: I guess the key is that the open balls are a basis for the  usual topology on $\Bbb R^n$.  Now I think you should show how one gets those sets., namely, by pulling back open intervals  under the projection maps, and taking finite intersections and arbitrary unions..  I think this is somewhat nontrivial and needs to be checked.

Comment: I think you actually get a 'box', not 'ball', and thsi topology is sometimes callled the box topology.  But it winds up being ok.  Because the product is finite.